# Finding identical rows in Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to find rows with identical data. I can't quite wrap my head around how the sql would work, but I know what the result should look like:

```
USER__IP (as uip1) [
    id,
    ip,
    user_id,
    USER__IP (as uip2) [
        id,
        ip,
        user_id (where uip2.user_id != uip1.user_id)
    ]
]
```

To explain; I have a model (USER__IP) which I've simplified above. Many users may share the same ip, and I want to know who. I made some comments in parantheses above which illustrates where I wish to go with this. I hope it is comprehensable.

I guess this needs to be written as two queries, first one that selects all USER__IP, and another which selects it's related entities. I tried with something like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function userIp() {
        return $this->hasMany('UserIp');
    }
}

class UserIp extends Eloquent {
    public function identical() {
        return $this->hasMany('UserIp', 'ip', 'ip')->whereNotIn('user_id', array($this->user_id));
    }
}

// Run from the controller, and return the result.
$user = User::with(array('user_ips' => function ($query) {
    $query->with('identical');
}))->findOrFail($userId);
```

This does not provide the desired results. Somehow `$this->user_id` is bound to the query as `null`, and I don't get why.

The question is; given this model, how can I produce the desired result using either Eloquent or Query builder directly? Thank you.

**Edit**

I realize that I simplified the procedure too much. I therefore added the real controller code in the code above.

**Edit 2**

So the best solution to this problem was to do what @c-griffin proposed. Since his solution was in my opinon not quite complete, rather than answering my own question with the working code, I will just place an edit here and mark his answer as the correct one:

```
class UserIp extends Eloquent {
    public function identical() {
        return $this->hasMany('UserIp', 'ip', 'ip');
    }
}

// Controller code
$user = User::findOrFail($userId);
$user->load(array('user_ips' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
        $query->with(array('identical' => function ($q) use ($userId) {
                $q->whereNotIn('user_id', array($userId));
            }));
    }));
```

Thank you guys for your help in this.

Comment: *$this->user_id* is empty because it is being called statically *UserIp:with(..)*

Comment: Actually, there's a layer on top of that again. Check the edit I made to the controller code above. You are saying that this cannot be done Unless I loop over each User programatically and invoke identical() using user->id as a parameter to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be completely missing the boat on what you're trying to do, but this could work.
Leave your relationship as bare-bones as possible, then specify your `where`s in `with()`s closure.

```
class UserIp extends Eloquent {
    public function identical() {
        return $this->hasMany('UserIp', 'ip', 'ip');
    }
}
```

---

```
// in a controller method
UserIp::with(['identical' => function($query){
    $query->whereNotIn('user_id', array($this->user_id));
}])->get();
```

Comment: Ok, you moved the whereNotIn out of the identical(), which would mean that I would always need to specify whereNotIn every time I call this method. Otherwise identical() would allways return at least the current master row - which is definately undesired. Is it not possible to make the whereNotIn default to the identical() method?

Comment: As you mentioned, `$this->user_id` is null un your relationship.  So you you have a couple choices.  I use Sentry, when i dump `Sentry::getUser()->id` in a relationship, i have a value.  I would imagine it works the same with the stock `Auth` driver, so try replacing `$this->user_id` with `Auth::user()->id`.... Or, set `$this->user_id` in a constructor somewhere (`BaseController` maybe). (didn't test this one)

Comment: I took your solution and rewrote it to fit with what I'm trying to achieve. It worked as expected. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$userIps = $userip = UserIp::get();
foreach ($userIps as $userIp)
{
    $userIp->load('identical');
}
```

Comment: Ok, again I'm asking; is this impossible to do unless I loop over the resultset programmatically?